# Windows 10: music fades a lot when another sound plays at the same time

Tags: windows-10, audio, windows-10-v1903

I am using Windows 10 Pro 1903. My problem is that if I am (for example) playing music and another sound, like a notification, plays at the same time, the original audio (the music) fades down for a long time (several seconds) and fades *a lot*, to the point of being almost inaudible.

This has started happening in recent updates (about a couple of months ago). I am using an AMD X399 motherboard with a Realtek audio chip, using the Realtek High Definition driver.